# How to use SELECT with dynamic column names in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, dynamic

I have set an extended property to flag a set of columns. I can retrieve the column list like this:

```
SELECT objname 
FROM fn_listextendedproperty (NULL,'user','dbo','table','my_table','column',NULL)
    WHERE (name LIKE 'MyExtendedPropertyFlag' AND value = '1')
```

How would I then produce a query (on this same table, my_table) that uses this column list and returns all records where any value from this column list is NULL?